# How to call component function in jest

Tags: reactjs, mount, jestjs

My component code roughly looks like below

```
class HomePageGrid extends React.Component {
 //component code
}
export default StateHoc(HomePageGrid);
export {HomePageGrid as PureHomePageGrid};
```

I have following code in my test case

```
it("Checks whether state changes on moveUp", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<PureHomePageGrid />);
    var inst = wrapper.instance();
    inst.state.cardCurrentFocus = 1;
    inst.moveUp();
    expect(inst.state.cardCurrentFocus).toBe(0);
  });
```

I get the following error

```
inst.moveUp is not afunction
```

I tried using wrapper.dive().instance(). But then I get the following error

```
 wrapper.dive is not a function
```

it seems like dive works with only shallow. Then how to call a function of a component in jest when the component is mounted?

Comment: How does your `PureHomePageGrid` component look like

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have edited the question with roughly how my component is exported